# Translate python request to javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, fetch

I'm trying to translate some python code into javascript code, however I can't get it to work. For some reason my javascript code isn't sending the same request as the python code (see my code below).

My javascript implementation:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("URL", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-Scope": "SOME NUMBERS",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({signature: studentId}),
  });
};
```

Here is the javascript request:

```
{
   "headers":{
      "host":URL,
      "x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-61291bf7-72b84b7d2e9f7f4554960116",
      "content-length":"27",
      "x-scope":X_SCOPE_CODE,
      "accept":"*/*",
      "content-type":"application/json",
      "user-agent":"Expo/2.21.3.10300 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/17.7.0",
      "accept-language":"en-us",
      "accept-encoding":"br, gzip, deflate"
   },
   "body":{
      "signature":STUDENT_ID_HERE
   },
   "inferred_body_type":"JSON",
   "method":"POST",
   "url":URL,
   "client_ip":MY_IP,
   "query":{
      
   }
}
```

Original python implementation:

```
headers = {"X-Scope": "SOME NUMBERS", "Content-Type":"application/json"}
data={"signature":studentId}
response = requests.post("URL", headers=headers, json=data)
```

Here is what the python request looks like:

```
{
   "headers":{
      "host":URL,
      "x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-61291d14-232a885c5c568ea9439203cc",
      "content-length":"28",
      "user-agent":"python-requests/2.26.0",
      "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
      "accept":"*/*",
      "x-scope":X_SCOPE,
      "content-type":"application/json"
   },
   "body":{
      "signature":STUDENT_ID
   },
   "inferred_body_type":"JSON",
   "method":"POST",
   "url":URL,
   "client_ip":MY_IP,
   "query":{
      
   }
}
```

Comment: In what way does the resulting request differ?

Comment: I'm trying to access an external API, but the python request contains the correct information in the response and javascript doesn't  - there for I assumed the requests must differ. @David

Comment: Looks like it's just a typo.  The object being JSON-serialized is missing the `{}` object syntax: `JSON.stringify({ signature: studentId })`

Comment: The typo was made here on stackoverflow. The code doesn't work with even with the typo corrected. I'm sorry about that. @David

Comment: What other differences exist between the code you're showing us and the actual code you're using?  When you debug and inspect the requests, in what way(s) do they differ?

Comment: Here is the python request: `POST URL_HERE
X-Scope: X_SCOPE_HERE
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28

b'{"signature": STUDENT_ID_HERE}'` @David

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch <-- look at the JSON examples and you will see what you messed up, there is no `data`

Comment: I still get the wrong reponse, even with the correct parameter @epascarello

Comment: So what is wrong... hard to guess... the Error from the server is? What does your HTTP request look like in the debugger?

Comment: Updated the post to show the javascript request in the debugger @epascarello

Comment: So what is the error from the server?

Comment: There is no error, but the server sends different responses. It's an external API so I don't know why. Updated the post to include the python request debugger aswell @epascarello

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, the 'data' parameter is called 'body'.
Your request looks like it should work after changing this.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("URL", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-Scope": "SOME NUMBERS",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({signature: studentId}),
  });
};
```

Comment: I still get the wrong response, even with the correct parameter.

Comment: @hampani What exactly is the 'wrong response'? Judging by your edits, the requests look functionally identical.